# How to minus 20 to a number in HTML using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm doing a project and I can't figure out how I can use just javascript's function to call it in a button,this button decrements healthpoints by -20 each time the button is clicked. I'm basic in knowledge of javascript. Here is my code: Regarding HTML code `<span id="hpFirst">0</span>` However I did override the 0, what do I do it seems to simple, I just want to click a button and decrement it without changing layout.

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Idle War</title>
</head>
<body id="textChanger">
        <h1>IDLE WAR</h1><h2><time>00:00:00</time></h2>
                     <h3 id="title">Player One:</h3>
                     <table style="width:100%">
                         <tr>
                             <th>Health:</th>
                             <td><span id="hpFirst">0</span>/1100healthpoints</td>
                         <tr>
                             <th>Experience Pts:</th>
                             <td>0</td>
                         </tr>                       
                     </table>
    <h3><span id="hpFirst2">&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;0</span><span>/1100</span> healthpoints</h3>
    <h3>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp; Experience Pts: <span id="Exp">0</span></h3>
    <p>
        You are PlayerOne and start at<span> 1100</span> healthpoints.       
    </p>
    <p>
        <button type="button" id="textChanger2" value="MinusOne" onclick="myFunction(); updateAll(); getTextColor(); getTextColor2(); minusHealth();">Hunt</button>
    </p>

    <button id="start">start</button>
    <button id="stop">stop</button>
    <button id="clear">clear</button>
    <script src="Idlewar.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS code:

```
function updateAll() {
    document.getElementById("Exp").innerHTML = experiencePoint;
    document.getElementsById("hpFirst").innerHTML = healthPoint;
    document.getElementById("character").innerHTML = playerone;

}

var playerone = 0;
var experiencePoint = 0;
var healthPoint = 1100;

var h2 = document.getElementsByTagName('h2')[0];
var start = document.getElementById('start');
var stop = document.getElementById('stop');
var clear = document.getElementById('clear');
var seconds = 0, minutes = 0, hours = 0,
    t;

var results = "";

document.getElementById("textChanger").onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("hpFirst").innerHTML = "1100";
}
document.getElementById("textChanger2").onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById("hpFirst2").innerHTML = "1100";
}
function minusHealth() {
    document.getElementById("hpFirst").value = healthPoint;
    healthPoint -= 20;
}
function getTextColor() {
    var hpColorText = document.getElementById("hpFirst");    
    if (healthPoint >= 501) {
        hpColorText.style.color = 'green';
    }
    else if (healthPoint <= 500) {
        hpColorText.style.color = 'red';
    }
}
function getTextColor2() {   
    var hpColorText = document.getElementById("hpFirst2");
    if (healthPoint >= 501) {
        hpColorText.style.color = 'green';
    }
    else if (healthPoint <= 500) {
        hpColorText.style.color = 'red';
    }
}
function add() {

    seconds++;
        if (seconds >= 60) {
            seconds = 0;
            minutes++;
            if (minutes >= 60) {
                minutes = 0;
                hours++;
            }
        }

        h2.textContent = (hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) : "00") + ":"
            + (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00") + ":"
            + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);
        timer();
        getTextColor();
        getTextColor2();
}
function timer() {
    t = setTimeout(add, 1000);

    }
timer();
getTextColor();
getTextColor2();
function myFunction() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        results += rollDie() + " ";
        if (numberRandom >= 1 || numberRandom <= 5) {
            healthPoint -= 50;
            experiencePoint += 3;
        }
    }    
}

/* Start button */
start.onclick = timer;

/* Stop button */
stop.onclick = function () {
    clearTimeout(t);
    }

/* Clear button */
clear.onclick = function () {
    h2.textContent = "00:00:00";
    seconds = 0; minutes = 0; hours = 0;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `<button onClick="minusHealth()">Click</button>`?

Comment: any errors in the developer tools console?

Comment: @user70960 - `onclick="myFunction(); updateAll(); getTextColor(); getTextColor2(); minusHealth();"` seems OP has done that

Comment: you're missing an element with id="character" and one with id="textChanger" ... which means you get errors on page load ... and a function called `rollDie`, so the onclick fails at `myFunction` therefore `minusHealth` is never called ...  I stopped looking after that - you should use the browser **developer** tools console to debug your code further

Comment: Ok, I'm getting a lot of feedback, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You just override the click event here:

```
document.getElementById("textChanger2").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("hpFirst2").innerHTML = "1100";
}
```

So the onclick in html don't work.

**Edited**

On the other hand, you have some errors as below:

1. character not defined
2. getElementsById should be getElementById
3. numberRandom is not defined
4. rollDie is not defined

Hope this help you.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks.

Comment: If this really help, you should mark it as the answer. Or if the answer is still not accurate, please tell me. Thanks!